# .$ajax don't work in SpringBoot SELECT. Can get any solution?

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, select

I need some help with this. I have search for a solution for weeks, and I can't get the solution. I do the same as other solutions and they don't work.

I'm sending you examples of what I'm doing, because I'm trying to do simple things before more complex tasks.

I'm trying to make a SELECT that Post information to a Spring controller and take a reply.

The first two alerts are OK, but there is no reply from $ajax.

Please, help!

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-2">
                    <label for="provinciaFormador">Provincia</label>
                        <select th:field="*{provincia.idProvincia}" class="form-control" id="provinciaFormador">
                            <option th:each="provincia:${provincias}"
                                th:text="${provincia.nombreProvincia}"
                                th:value="${provincia.idProvincia}">
                            </option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    
                        <!-- Script -->
                    
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    $("#provinciaFormador").change(
                        function cargaLocal() {
                          var idProvincia = document.getElementById("provinciaFormador").value;
                          alert(idProvincia);
                          alert("prueba");
                          var nombreProvincia = {}
                          nombreProvincia ["nombreProvincia"] = "prueba";
                            
                            $.ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                contentType : "application/json",
                                url : "/cargaLocal",
                                data : JSON.stringify(nombreProvincia),
                                dataType : "json",
                                success : function(data) {
                                    alert("2");
                                    }                
                                });
                            });
```

As you see, it is only an example. All results are not real, but I can't get them.

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cargaLocal", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String provincia (@RequestBody ProvinciaEscogida provinciaEscogida) {
    System.out.println(provinciaEscogida.getNombreProvincia());
    return "prueba";
}
```

The  helper java .class:

```
public class ProvinciaEscogida {
        
        private String nombreProvincia;
    
        //Getters y setters
}
```

Comment: Start by learning how to inspect the ajax request in browser dev tools network (F12) where you can see exactly what is sent, status, headers, what is returned in response body etc. Also you have no error handler. By doing such debugging you can start to isolate if problem is in js or server code

Comment: Thank you! I'll follow you're suggest!

Comment: Aparently I have no error in handler or html, but succes function still don't work. In browser dev tools the responses are all as I expect, but succes function do not run. I started with a simply alert to be sure it works, as you can see.

Comment: Are you returning json data? If not you set `dataType` to expect it

Comment: I'm returning a String for testing. The idea is to do step by step until all works. Can the succes function work despite the data object is used as written above? I think it should, shouldn't it?

Comment: A string is not json, try commenting out dataType

Comment: It's working now. So many thanks! As you can see I'm an absolute noob in javascript trying to do some complex things. But I read all I can and I'm learning as fast as I can. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

**nombreProvincia ["nombre_rovincia"] = "prueba";**

Make sure that you have no args constructor, not only setter/getter

```
public class ProvinciaEscogida {
    public ProvinciaEscogida() {}
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Now I have the request, but succes function still don't work despite being only an alert

Comment: Because your response is not a valid JSON, IMO. You should return a JSON ie: `return "{}";`